# pandas 0.24.1 Key Error: "None of [Index(['A' 'B'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

Tags: python, pandas

Formerly I had anaconda with pandas 0.18. Using the code below, I made a calculation by the function "calc_func" and assign the result to the the columns of DataFrame, say "A" and "B".

```
df[["A", "B"]]=df.[["KV", "GV"]].apply(calc_func, axis=1)
```

After upgrading the pandas to 0.24.1, this code yields a KeyError as "None of [Index(['A' 'B'], dtype='object')] are in the [columns]"

I have tried the code below but got the same error.

```
df.loc[:,["A", "B"]]=df.loc[:,["KV", "GV"]].apply(calc_func, axis=1)
```

Any help would be highly appreciated.

My calc_func below:

```
def calc_func (_dataframe):

    _limit15=v_limit15.get()
    _limit20=v_limit20.get()
    kvm=_veritabani["KV"]
    gvm=_veritabani["GV"]
    if kvm+gvm<=_limit15:
        gvo=0.15
        gv=gvm*gvo
    elif kvm+gvm>_limit15 and kvm<=_limit15:
        gv=(kvm+gvm-_limit15)*0.20+(_limit15-kvm)*0.15
        gvo=gv/gvm
    elif kvm>_limit15 and kvm+gvm<=_limit20:
        gvo=0.20
        gv=gvm*gvo
        gvo=gv/gvm
    elif kvm+gvm>_limit20 and kvm<=_limit20:
        gv=(kvm+gvm-_limit20)*0.27+(_limit20-kvm)*0.20
        gvo=gv/gvm

    return [gvo, gv]
```

Comment: Hard test with no sample function, but how working `df[["A", "B"]] = pd.DataFrame(df[["KV", "GV"]].apply(calc_func, axis=1), index=df.index)` ?

Comment: There is no another change in my program. Just an update pandas from 0.18 to 0.24.

Comment: I added my calc_func.

Comment: @jezrael thanks for your help. This works.

Comment: Super, answer was edited.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change function for return `Series` with specify index:

```
return pd.Series([gvo, gv], index=['A','B'])
```